# Update Software Version in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, pysam

I have installed python and many other useful tools on my Ubuntu 14.04 using Anaconda. I installed pysam (htslib interface for python) using

```
conda install pysam
```

However this installs the old version (0.6). The current version is 0.8.4. How can I install that version using conda. I don't want to use `pip install pysam` because I read somewhere it might cause problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda only provides version 0.6. You can install from binstar with:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/uhlitz pysam
```

This should give you version 0.8.3 for linux64. [Other channels](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pysam) are also available.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean I have to stick with 0.6 if I have linux32?

Comment: I could [not find](https://anaconda.org/search?q=platform%3Alinux-32+pysam) any linux32 packages. Sorry.